# Removing Drop-Down Indicators from Top Level Menu ONLY

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I am working on: https://www.thewellnessproject.net/

I want to keep the drop-down indicators in the sub-menu (as shown under "Recipes"), however I would like to remove them from the top level menu (Recipes, Intuitive Eating, etc.).

I've tried something along the lines of the below, but with no success:

```css
.menu-item-6194 a:after {
   display: none;
}
```

Happy to provide any additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I just inspected the source code of your page. Based on that, use below snippets.

```
for(count=1; count<=5; count++)
{

    var main = getElementsByClassName("elementor-item")[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[i];
    main.classList.add("remove_dropdown_arrow");

}
```

Paste above code in cusotm JS section of WordPress.

```
.remove_dropdown_arrow{
    display:none;
}
```

Paste above code in custom CSS section of WordPress.

The gist is, I am getting all top level elements of main header menu. Then looping and adding a custom CSS class in element where we have ">" in items.

I hope this will work in one go, but you might need some tweak on your side.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I believe I did as you requested but I'm not positive; before I "tweak" would you mind confirming you are seeing everything properly?

Comment: What are you referring to ?

Comment: I added the css to the Elementor element, and added the JS script in my header code - but it doesn't seem to be working? Just want to make sure they are in the right place and captured correctly.

Comment: Not in Elementor element. Add the code in Dashboard>Appearance>Customize>Custom CSS/JS. Add CSS part in CSS section and JS part in JavaScript section. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I put here: js/main.js ...still doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I am not sure about main.js file. Can you try to put in above path I mentioned ?

Comment: Ahh yes, this is originally where I placed it and it didn't seem to work. Any other ideas? No worries if not; appreciate the help!